# Круглая кнопка с прогресс-баром

Tags: android

Хочу сделать кнопку с прогресс баром вокруг нее и чтобы при нажатии этот прогресс бар начал движение, когда дошел до конца(5секунд) - выполнился метод onClick.

Пример кнопки:

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

В теории я придумал так сделать:

Сама кнопка - это `ImageButton`
в нее засунуть гифку и как-то запускать анимацию гифки при нажатии.
Но я не силен в графике и в моем понимании сделать такую гифку ооочень тяжело;)

Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: Можно воспользоваться [готовым решением](https://github.com/ckurtm/FabButton)

Comment: Если задача сделать именно такую кнопочку с плавной анимацией и красивыми тенями.
1 - слой статическая картинка кнопки с прозрачными тенями. Ее можно сделать в inkspace без особых проблем, программисту конечно немножно долго :) , но ничего не возможного.
2 - слой снизу, под картинкой анимированная полоска. Полоску рисовал бы на canvas через drawable.

Comment: Задача не совсем такая, точнее не точно такую же кнопку сделать) Но суть почти такая же, есть картинка - круглая кнопка, а вокруг нее нужно добавить зеленую полоску, которая будет серая, если ничего не делать, а когда пользователь зажмет кнопку - полоска начнет ползти-заполняться и когда дойдет до конца - выполнится onClick кнопки.

Comment: [Тут похожая кнопка на css стиле](http://vladmaxi.net/web-developer/css/css-chekboks-s-privlekayushhim-effektom.html). Можешь подкрутить под себя.